# hash enumeration and using outside arguments

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form builder and the normal |f| variable.  In the middle I'd like to iterate over some hash and get a list of keys by which to build the form.  How can I incorporate "f" as an argument to the enumerator.

```
<%= form_for ..... do |f| %>
<% available_types.each do |k,v| %>
  <%= f.text_filed :selection, :value => v %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

As you can see in the code above, "f" is outside of the scope.  Ideas?

Comment: If you indented your code better, you'd be more likely to realize that `f` was in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` should still be in the scope. You misspelled `text_field` though.

Comment: I apologize, my bad! I put something else that caused the error.  f infact was in scope.